# C# Verbatim doesn't seem to work with .startinfo.arguments?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, verbatim

I have an app with which i can select from multiple MSI's (same msi, different versions) in a directory, and i will be able to install or uninstall from this app.

I pull in the list of MSI's, complete with full path, with

```
string MSILocation = @"C:\test\";
string[] MSIFiles = Directory.GetFiles(MSILocation, "*.MSI", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

From here i populate a listview, and once one is selected i hit the install button.
But when i go through my installing code, the verbatim seems to screw up.

```
string MSIname = lboMSIList.SelectedItem.ToString();
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "MSIEXEC.EXE";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/i " + MSIname;
p.Start();
```

Even though the listview shows the file with single / the end result always comes out with double /

Somewhere in there its losing the literal string.

If i change the code up and run *.FileName = @"msiexec.exe /i C:\test\test1.msi"* it works just fine, but i need to be able to select from a list of filenames.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it çome out' with `\\` in a debugger view?  That's just the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string MSILocation = @"C:\test\"; 
string[] MSIFiles = Directory.GetFiles(MSILocation, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToArray();
```

use above `MSIFiles`  array of file names to populate the listview

Use [Path.combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) as below

```
string MSILocation = @"C:\test\";
string MSIname = lboMSIList.SelectedItem.ToString();
Process p = new Process();  
p.StartInfo.FileName = "MSIEXEC.EXE"; 
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(
"{0} {1}", @"/i",Path.Combine(MSILocation , MSIname );  
p.Start();
```

Comment: Path.combine seems to fix it.  Frustrating problem, thanks for the help